# Is my Angular 8 route not working because its hierarchy is too deep?

Tags: angular, routes, angular8

I've stripped my app-routing.module.ts down its essentials for clarity...

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "home",
        component: HomeComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'sites/:filter',
                component: SiteListComponent,
                children: [
                    {
                        path: 'setup/:id',
                        component: SetupComponent,
                        children: [
                            {
                                path: 'summary',
                                component: SummaryComponent
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

When browse to the route `/home/sites/all/setup/48/summary` I get exactly the same result as when I browse to just `/home/sites/all`, meaning...

1. The view in the browser is exactly the same (it's rendering SiteListComponent's html)
2. Neither SetupComponent nor SummaryComponent are reached - their ngOnInit() functions do not get called. It's as though they are invisible to the routing engine.

The `<routing-outlet>` is in app.component.html.

- Is it obvious to anyone why this is?!
- Is there a limit to route nesting?
- Any suggestions on where I should look? I've tried everything I can think of.

Thank you so much.

FYI, the same components *are* hit and render as expected with this routing config...

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'site-setup/:id',
        component: SetupComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'summary',
                component: SummaryComponent,
                data: { label: 'Site Setup - Summary' }
            }
        ]
    }
];
...
```

...SummaryComponent is reached and rendered with this url `site-setup/48/summary`

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you have to specify your routes as follow(instead of nest it). Please consider important the order of each route as well:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "home",
        component: HomeComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'sites/:filter/setup/:id/summary',
        component: SummaryComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'sites/:filter/setup/:id',
        component: SetupComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'sites/:filter',
        component: SiteListComponent
    },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Hope this help.